# <li> element problems in navigation bar

Tags: html

I am making a navigation bar, but w3 validator is giving me the following error:

Element a not allowed as child of element ul in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)

With code like this:

```
<ul id="main-nav">
    <a href="'.$index.'"><logo></logo></a>
    <li><a href="'.$index.'" title="Home page ">Home</a></li>
</ul>
```

I tried to change the menu around, but I couldn't fix it. What would be a simple fix?

E: the logo tag displays the logo

```
ul#main-nav logo{

    background: url('images/logo.jpg') no-repeat;
    width: 250px;
    height: 54px;
    display: block;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your `<a>` element, not the `<li>`. The only valid child of `<ul>` is `<li>`. From the [W3 Docs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/ul.html):

> #### Permitted contents
>
> Zero or more [`li`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/li.html#li) elements

You should update your code as follows:

```
<ul id="main-nav">
    <li><a href="'.$index.'"><logo></logo></a></li>
    <li><a href="'.$index.'" title="Home page ">Home</a></li>
</ul>
```

There is no tag called `<logo>`, by the way... If you want the logo to appear outside the list, use:

```
<a href="'.$index.'"><logo></logo></a>
<ul id="main-nav">
    <li><a href="'.$index.'" title="Home page ">Home</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this line: `<a href="'.$index.'"><logo></logo></a>`

The only element that can be the child of a `ul` tag is an `li` tag;
all other tags are forbidden.

Try this:

```
<a href="'.$index.'"><logo></logo></a>
<ul id="main-nav">
    <li><a href="'.$index.'" title="Home page ">Home</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Child of a ul must be a 'list-item' ie li and in your case you have entered a hyperlink, hence the error.  [This](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/lists.html)  might help.